# Independence between random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Say I have four random variables: $X$, $Y$, $A$, and $B$. Now say that $X$ and $A$ are independent, $X$ and $B$ are independent, $Y$ and $A$ are independent, and $Y$ and $B$ are independent. Does this imply that $f(X, Y)$ and $g(A, B)$ are independent for some real functions $f$ and $g$? Note that $X$ and $Y$ may not be independent, same with $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I guess they are independant.

Comment: could you give some intuition as to why?

Comment: Well I'm not an expert in probability. Anyway the probability that $f(X,Y)=c$ is the same as $(x,y)\in f^-(c)$, and $x,y$ doing something is independent by $A,B$ doing something. That's what I think.

Comment: You really mean 'for any real measurable functions f and g'. If you want some f and g you can take both to be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independence cannot be handled by intuition alone. The answer to the  question is NO! For example we can have events $D,E,F$ such that any two of them are independent but the three together are not. To simplify things take $Y=0$. It is given that X is independent of A as well as B. For X to be independent of $g(A,B)$ for any measurable function g it is necessary that X is jointly independent of X and Y and this may not be true. In particular take the three events $D,E,F$ mentioned above, take $X=I_D, A=I_E, B=I_F$ Let $g(a,b)=ab$. Then X and $g(A,B)$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following counter example.
Let $$X=U$$$$Y=U\oplus W$$$$A=V$$$$B=V\oplus W$$ where $U,V,W$ are i.i.d. uniform in $\{0,1\}$ and $\oplus$ stands for modulo-$2$ addition. It is easy to see that all the required independence relations are satisfied.

Now assume
$$f(x,y)=g(x,y)=x\oplus y.$$
Then we get $$f(X,Y)=g(A,B)=W$$
and hence, $f(X,Y)$ and $g(A,B)$ are not independent.